Temperature of Dripping Chicken Juices
I recently read about rotisserie chickens being cooked (rotating racks with different levels of doneness and racks of raw chickens being added intermittently) above a pan of cooked fries- I am wondering if the moisture coming out of the chicken has a temperature high enough to be safe ot drip on the fries.
If the temperature of the cells is high enough to release moisture, does that mean it is hot enough to kill bacteria? I feel like when I roast a chicken, it begins to "sweat" very early when the skin/bird is still extremely raw. Sorry if this is a stupid question but I feel like what I read in that book does not sound safe.
Book: The Flavor Thesaurus by Niki Segnit. Page 34, under "Chicken and Potato"
Thanks.

Are you able to quote the relevant section please? Perhaps there was something lost in translation so to speak, that makes this scenario a little less crazy.
As for the question of whether the juices released from the chicken as it cooks, are at a safe temperature. I think that question whilst interesting, is in this particular scenario, largely academic for the simple fact raw chicken can also drip "juices". Not cooking juices but rather liquid from inside the body of the chicken, or maybe moisture that accumulated from the packaging the chicken came in or as the cold chicken condensed water onto it's surface from the air as it was warming up. It could even drip a few drops of blood.
If the scenario you described is accurate. That of chickens, at various stages of cooking, suspended over already cooked French fries... then that's a big yikes in my book. Even if it isn't in Niki Segnit's.
